# Who is Little Severian?

Tags: the-book-of-the-new-sun

In *The Book of the New Sun*, the protagonist meets a little boy who bears the same name as him: Severian, usually called "little Severian" in the book to disambiguate.

Little Severian seems to just be a boy who happens to have the same name. It doesn't seem to be a very rare name; it's even mentioned that it's one of those names that come in pairs, where a brother and sister will be called Severian and Severa, which is the case with Little Severian (and perhaps even "big" Severian, who doesn't know his family). Little Severian has a family and seems to just be a normal kid.

In *Urth of the New Sun*, however, Severian has this enigmatic line:

> I felt as real as I ever have; and when I searched among my memories, I found Valeria there still, and Thecla and old Autarch, and the boy Severian (who had been Severian only).

By this time in the narrative, we know that

> Severian has traveled back and forth in time, and even possibly encountered himself in the inn where he was attacked by the zombie. Is Little Severian himself as a child?

How can that be, when Severian has apparently figured out his mother's identity, and Little Severian has another mother (Casdoe)?

> Perhaps I was too distant from myself, from the Severian of bone and flesh borne by Catherine in a cell of the oubliette under the Matachin Tower.

Who is this boy really? What is his relation to "big" Severian?

> And why can't Severian resurrect him?

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks for the edit – it reminded me if this question, and of this possibly relevant Urth mailing list post I read recently: http://lists.urth.net/pipermail/urth-urth.net/2006-August/002782.html